# autohotkey GUI relate dynamically created button with edit control

Tags: autohotkey

I'm creating a GUI with autohotkey where the user can add elements dynamically. There is a plus button that allows you to add new edit controls. Those edit controls should have buttons next to them to do actions on the text they contain such split, replace etc. I know that I can get which button triggered the label (AKA click handler) but I don't know how to know to which edit control is it related.

The edit control and the button are under the same section in a GroupBox, I don't know if that can help. How can I determine which button of which edit control have been pressed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you provide button and edit with fitting variables? Let's say, `button1` and `edit1` for the first group, `button2`,`edit2` for the second etc... a code example would also be much appreciated. Maybe some1 else can help you further

Comment: Ello Blauhirn. I ended using something similar to what you suggested. Please take a look to my answer to see if you know how to address the problem about the space being reserved. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I got a partial solution using arrays. Not elegant but works.

```
num:=1
editBtn := Object()
groupBtn := Object()
Gui,+Border
Gui,Add,GroupBox,x4 y-1 w140 h40 Section,controls
Gui,Add,Button,x8 y14 w20 h20 gaddColumn,+
Gui,Add,GroupBox,x4 y42 w140 h80 Section,Column1
Gui, Add, Edit, 20 vMyEdit xs+10 ys+20,
Gui,Show,x469 y131 w374 h485 AutoSize,
Return
addColumn:
    num +=1
    Gui,Add,GroupBox,x4 y+10 w140 h80 vGroup%num% Section,Column%num%
    Gui,Add,Button, w20 h20 xs+100 ys+10  gremCol vBtnCol%num%,-
    Gui, Add, Edit, 20 vMyEdit%num% xs+10 ys+30,
    editBtn["BtnCol" . num] := "MyEdit" . num
    groupBtn["BtnCol" . num] := "Group" . num
    gui, show, AutoSize

Return
GuiClose:
ExitApp
Return

remCol:
 ; MsgBox,,, % A_GuiControl colBtns[A_GuiControl]
 GuiControl, Hide, % A_GuiControl
 GuiControl, Hide, % editBtn[A_GuiControl]
 GuiControl, Hide, % groupBtn[A_GuiControl]
 gui, show, AutoSize
Return
```

The problem is that I can only use hide to remove elements. This have an ugly drawback: if I remove an element and then I add another one it "reserves" the space of the first one.

Comment: yeah, it's a shame that `guiControl, delete` hasn't been implemented yet. Help file suggests to destroy and recreate the entire window via Gui Destroy. Alternatively, you could define a static counter variable, let's call it `y_`, and set it to 150. After each `addColumn`, you'll increase it by 100, with each `remCol`, you'll decrease it by 100. Finally, your line in `addColumn` should be like `Gui,Add,GroupBox,x4 y%y_% w140 etc..`. Hope you understand. Worked for me.

Comment: Hello Blauhirn. I don't see the need of using an auxiliar variable since ahk manages this itself. xs and ys contains positioning relative to the previously added element,so all you need to do is ys+20 when adding for example. I think the best approach is to use arrays to "store" the elements,then when clicking the delete button remove that element from the array and re-create the entire guy using the info on the arrays. I don't know how slow this can be. You also needs to save the value of all the edit items, right?